# Issue with distinguishing levels in isometric game

Tags: 2d, graphics, isometric, graphics-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change this isometric engine to make it so that you could distinguish between blocks that are on different planes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20360/how-can-i-change-this-isometric-engine-to-make-it-so-that-you-could-distinguish)

I'm working on an isometric game however I am having trouble visually distinguishing between levels in the game.

Take the example below, the first image shows concrete blocks at ground level and the following images show an attempt to build a few blocks a level above. As you can see the level above is visually swallowed the one below.

[image]

I've tried shading to make lower levels darker with respect to camera, but this doesn't work that well.. any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try highlighting the edges of elevated blocks to illustrate the difference in depth.

Like so:

[image: Isometric blocks with highlights]

Comment: Or, ideally, create more descriptive edge-states for blocks, real edges that fade from stone floor to falling rocky edge to cliff on all sides and where two at the same level meet, are replaced with flat connections. [Like this.](http://ianbarefoot.com/temp/mockup_v2.png)